# Defining a global int and two dimensional matrix with #define in C

Tags: c, matrix, global-variables

so I'm having a little problem with #define in C. I'm sure it's just a little syntax issue, but I can't seem to find what it is after combing through several forums.

my code is:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define MAX_N (5)
#define m[MAX_N][MAX_N]


int wineProfitMemorized(int price[], int n, int begin, int end) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            m[i][j] = -99;
        }
    }
    int year = 0;
    ++year;
    if (begin > end) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (m[begin][begin] == -99){
        m[begin][begin] = price[begin] * year;
    }
    if (m[begin][end] == -99){
        m[begin][end] = price[end] * year;
    }
    return max(m[begin + 1][end] + m[begin][begin], m[begin][end - 1] + m[begin][end]);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is solve this wine-selling issue which originally was solved recursively with memoization.

I have to define those two variables MAX_N = 5 and the array m[MAX_N][MAX_N] so that I can access it further on in the dynamic programming approach I will face later on. I will have to print it out and fill it with values, so it can't be read-only.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with the #define? it's generating several errors in the method such as "missing ;" and "syntax error".

Comment: Question: What is the data type for `m`?

Comment: It should be int, but Tom Karzes solved it for me! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing macro definitions with variable declarations.  The first two macros are fine, but the third one needs to be changed to a declaration.  Just replace:

```
#define m[MAX_N][MAX_N]
```

with:

```
int m[MAX_N][MAX_N];
```

That should help.

Comment: Wow, that was it...thanks a lot!